# Importing documents from VSS to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, visual-sourcesafe

I'm looking to export a folder in VSS2005 which contains word documents. Is it possible to export this to a sharepoint document library through the use of a tool?

If possible, I would like to keep the version history.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to keep history and users identity, you can just open SharePoint library in Windows Explorer using button in ribbon of library. Then just copy all your documents.